# Correct Typing for a map of functional interfaces (Java 8)

Tags: java, generics, java-8, lambda

I'm trying to store a mapping of strings to functions in a HashMap and I'm struggling with getting the typing right. How do I store functions of varying types as defined by a generic functional interface?

Here is the relevant code.

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Converter<F,T> {
    T convert(F from);
}

 HashMap<String, Converter<?, ?>> fooMapping= new HashMap<String, Converter<?, ?>>();

 fooMapping.put("name", (someString) -> someString);
 fooMapping.put("flavor", (someInt) -> someAge + 1);
```

The last two lines don't compile with the following (obvious) errors:

-The method length() is undefined for the type Object
-The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) Object, int

So my question is how do I specify the TYPES F and T of Converter when I'm storing the lamda in my hashmap so I'm not forced to cast everything from Object?

Comment: FYI you can just use Function from java.util.function instead of your Converter FInterface. `HashMap<String, Function<?, ?>> fooMapping= new HashMap<String, Function<?, ?>>();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specify the type of the lambda parameter (`F`)

```
fooMapping.put("name", (String someString) -> someString.length());
fooMapping.put("flavor", (Integer someInt) -> someInt + 1);
```

The return type (`T`) will be inferred from the type of the lambda body expression.

Comment: DOH! Thanks. So obvious, I feel like such a noob. Playing with it some more I see that you can also cast the entire lambda `(Converter<String, String>)(someInt) -> someInt + 1`

Comment: @xtrakBandit Sure, that will set an explicitly typed target functional interface. Note that with `String`, you'll be doing String concatenation. `someInt` is inferred to be a `String`.

Comment: Thanks @SotiriosDelimanolis. Follow up question, when I call `fooMapping.get("someKey")` what will be the result type? Will the exact typing of the lambda be preserved?

Comment: No, your `fooMapping` is of type `HashMap<String, Converter<?,?>>`. The return type of `get` with be `Converter<?,?>`.

Comment: Thanks again. So I'm assuming this is a result of type erasure. Is there anyway of having a collection of lambdas of mixed type and calling them without casting?

Comment: @xtrakBandit No, type erasure has no bearing here. You've explicitly typed your `Converter`s with the wildcard `?`. You've explicitly stated that you either don't know what type is bound. If you don't know, how can the compiler?